# Number of online users and app visits in single page application

Tags: reactjs, angularjs, vue.js, single-page-application, svelte

I making a SPA (single page application) and want to show the number of online users and app visits in the admin panel like this:

online users: 5 people

Today visits: 12 people.

This Year visits: 5263 people.

I don't know what the proper procedure is for implementing this.

What I'm doing as a solution is to make an endpoint at the server for computing number of online users and visits. In the client I've created a random string as UserKey and saved it into `localStorage`.Then I've used `setInterval` to send a request with UserKey payload to the endpoint every 5 minutes. This endpoint calculates the number of online users and visits based on UserKey and current date and time. Calculating Is not 100% Accurate but it's satisfactory for me.

I'm not sure if I'm in the right way. Please share me your advice.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply do it with **Navigator.onLine** :
[Source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator/onLine)

Comment: I read about it in the link mentioned, But may you tell me how it can help me?

Comment: Here is an example. The rest is up to your imagination.
https://alligator.io/js/navigator-online/

Answer (score 0):

Websockets (pusher) should be a right solution for your case. This way you don't have to poll every 5 minutes.

See https://pusher.com/docs/channels/getting_started/javascript/?ref=docs-index
It is free but just for 50 users if you want more users you can also choose to start an own Websocket server. Which is a little more complicated (without external libraries of course).

Comment: Thanks but I don't think using sockets is a good way for this job, due to the presure it makes on the server